# Apache cxf delete request error

Tags: java, spring, cxf

I'm trying to use `@DELETE` request after a made some simple web application which I've tested using soapui. With this application I can add and get users/book to database. Now I'm trying to made a `@DELETE` request but I can't make it. Here is the code:

```
//UserServiceImpl

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;

    @Override
    public void deleteUser(Long id) {
        if (null == id || id.longValue() < 1) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(" User id can not be null or less than zero. ");
        }

        User u = em.find(User.class, id);
        em.remove(u);

    }

//UserResource

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @DELETE
    @Path("/delete/{id}")
    public Response deleteUser(@PathParam("id") String id) {
        Response response;
        try {
            User user = userService.deleteUser(Long.valueOf(id));//here is the error
            if (user != null) {
                response = Response.status(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK).entity(user).build();
            } else {
                response = Response.status(HttpServletResponse.SC_NOT_FOUND).build();
            }
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            response = Response.status(HttpServletResponse.SC_NOT_FOUND).build();
        }
        return response;
    }
```

Comment: No body can answer your question, until unless you provide explanation like what is the error your are facing. Stack trace etc

Comment: Probably it's about your transaction management. What is transaction definition of userservice.deleteUser(...) method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I`ve fix my problem. The delete method which is in UserServiceImpl must not be void.... it must be public User deleteUser(Long id). The other delete method in Resource class ... just need to be of void type. There i do not use Response and i simply print the result like this:

```
System.out.print(Response.status(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK).entity(user).build());
```